# Finder freeze when I go to any iCloud folder

Tags: icloud, finder, performance

Whenever I try to open any iCloud folder from the sidebar, Finder freeze and I have to restart it from the force stop window.

The only iCloud folder I **can** open is the main iCloud Drive folder, but it's just empty and says "loading" forever.

When I try to open the iCloud Progress Window, a weird thing happens:

[image: gif of the loading window]

As you can see the progress is always equal to the goal and that's really weird.

I already tried this in terminal and then restarting the Mac:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist && killall -HUP Finder
```

If you know what to do please answer thanks.

Comment: If any of this happens to you, TURN OFF ICLOUD DRIVE IN MAC SETTINGS RIGHT AWAY. After a couple of days I was unable to login my Mac because Finder was not opening on startup and nothing worked. I had to reboot my Mac and delete everything.

Comment: Okay, so I'm in this situation now, and I'm a little scared of turning off icloud drive, because that would mean that every file that didn't upload to the icloud server will be forever lost, wouldn't it?